# android firebase thread callback to another thread than main?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase

According to this:

> The Firebase Database client performs all network and disk operations
> off the main thread. The Firebase Database client invokes all
> callbacks to your code on the main thread.
>
> So network and disk access for the database are no reason to spin up
> your own threads or use background tasks. But if you do disk, network
> I/O or CPU intensive operations in the callback, you might need to
> perform those off the main thread yourself.

And yes, that's exactly what it does:

```
FireBaseValueEventListenerW postListener = new FireBaseValueEventListenerW() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            ****          MAIN THREAD     *****
                        }
                    };

                     ****          RANDOM THREAD     *****
                    ref.childInfoIndex()
                        .orderByChild(ReferenceInfo.Index.ref)
                        .limitToFirst(1)
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener);
```

And that's my problem. Is there a way to force firebase to answer in the same thread which made the request ?
An easy way without to be force you each to write your logic inside a runnable to push it back where it should be.

Thanks.

Comment: seems a terrible idea, why would you do that. Better leave the part as it is to what doc says, use rxjava or coroutines for post processing.

Comment: Because the work i'm doing inside the answer has nothing to do in the main thread ;). Anyway, I found a way I like.

Answer (score 0):

So an answer that suit to me giving me few and fast refactor:

to sum up:

- Just extend the listener
- Give it the handler you want
- Override the onDataChange and mark it as final
- Give another method which is done inside your thread

  public abstract class FireBaseValueEventListenerW implements ValueEventListener {
  private Handler handler;
  public FireBaseValueEventListenerW() {
  this(null);
  }
  public FireBaseValueEventListenerW(Handler handler) {
  TrackClass.create(this);
  this.handler = handler;
  }
  @Override
  final public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  if(handler != null) handler.post(this, new RunnableW() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  onDataChangeThread(snapshot);
  }
  });
  else onDataChangeThread(snapshot);;
  }
  public void onDataChangeThread(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

  ```
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        TrackClass.destroy(this);
        super.finalize();
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: for some reason, this code doesn't want to be formatted with the balise code... After 3-4 attempt, i gave.